# Error: "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback" when doing java -jar myproyect.jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, mqtt

I got that error when I tried to run my proyect using java -jar. My proyect is a MQTT server that has a controller class:

```
public class ControladorMQTT
```

and a callback class:

```
public class CallbackMQTT implements MqttCallback
```

and it seems that the callback clas is not beeing detected.

This is the complete error:

```
C:\Users\Moreno\Documents\IntelliJ\ControladorMQTT\out\artifacts\ControladorMQTT_jar>java -jar ControladorMQTT.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttCallback
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

I have the MANIFEST.MF created like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MQTT.ControladorMQTT
Class-Path: org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback
```

**EDIT**

I have added the library `C:\Users\Moreno\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\paho\org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3\1.2.0\org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar` into my application .jar directoy and I have modified the MANIFEST to look like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MQTT.ControladorMQTT
Class-Path: org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar
```

but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the external dependencies (jar files) into the classpath. Something like this:

```
java -cp C:\path\to\file.jar;C:\path\to\some-lib-jars\*;. -jar ControladorMQTT.jar
```

See:

- [java command documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624).

Answer (score 0):

Your Manifest `Class-Path:` declaration is wrong. See the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

It should contain the list of Jars holding the libraries you have used in your application. You have added a single class `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback`, this will not work.

It should read something like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MQTT.ControladorMQTT
Class-Path: paho-3.1.jar
```

And the paho-3.1.jar file should be in the same directory as your application jar.

Comment: But all the libraries I use are in Maven, I don't have the .jar of the library. Should I download and add it?

Comment: Just because the libraries were in your build environment doesn't mean they are in the runtime space.

Comment: I found the .jar in C:\Users\Moreno\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\paho\org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3\1.2.0 and I added it to the folder where I have my application .jar. ALso, I modified the Manifest and I added the name of the library .jar to the class-path and I still have the same error

Comment: EDIT the question to include fall new Manifest, and all the filenames and relative paths.