# Exception NoClassDefFoundError while initializing MqttWireMessage

Tags: java, android, encoding, mqtt

When I try to run my app on an API17 device I've got this error:

```
Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lorg/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/internal/wire/MqttWireMessage;
```

The eclipse mqtt is implemented in the gradle like this:

```
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.5'
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
```

I see that

> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttWireMessage

have these encoding:

```
protected static final Charset STRING_ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
```

The StandardCharsets support min Android API19 and this code is working OK when is running on my devices with API>19.

How can I solve this problem if I need to run my app on API17 devices?

Comment: External dependencies are not getting resolved. You need to add them to the `classpath`.

Comment: @Amitkumar thanks for your suggestion. Can you be more precise? What dependencies should I add and how?

Comment: Please refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563649/error-caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-eclipse-paho-client-mqt